# SQL DB2 dynamic date select rolling 6 months with second variable pulling last month

Tags: sql, date, variables, db2, sequence

I have a daily price table that updates only on business days. I am trying to create two dynamic date variables that allow me to pull a rolling 6 months view of the max date in each month and a second variable based off the first that has a corresponding last month end max date (so essentially 7 month-ends).

Here is my code, but I am not sure where to go from here. Should I be using functions like DATEDIFF, or GROUP BY and then PARTITION on MONTH or create a sequencer and start counting rows? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
WITH dtt as (SELECT
CURRENT_DATE - DAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAYS V_EOM1,
CURRENT_DATE - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE)-1) DAYS - 1 MONTH - 1 DAY V_EOM2
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)

SELECT
dph.ID,
V_EOM1,
dph.AMT_PRCE AS PRICE,
V_EOM_LAST,
fpr2.AMT_PRCE AS LAST_PRICE

FROM dtt LEFT JOIN
      UDBADM.D_PRICE_HIST dph
      ON dph.DT_PRCE = V_EOM1 LEFT JOIN
      UDBADM.D_PRICE_HIST dph2
      ON dph.ID = dph2.ID AND dph2.DT_PRCE = dtt.V_EOM_LAST

WHERE dph.ID = '444128'
```

This is what I am currently getting if I just pull 1 month rolling with end of  month from the previous (last) month:

```
ID       V_EOM        PRICE  V_EOM_LAST   LAST_PRICE
444128   10/31/2016   2700   09/30/2016   2600
```

This is what I am trying to achieve by pulling a rolling 6 months of the max date of each month (notice April and July month-ends fall on the weekend, so the max date is not the last calendar day of the month):

```
ID       V_EOM        PRICE  V_EOM_LAST   LAST_PRICE
444128   05/31/2016   2550   04/29/2016   2750
444128   06/30/2016   2500   05/31/2016   2550
444128   07/29/2016   2400   06/30/2016   2500
444128   08/31/2016   2650   07/29/2016   2400
444128   09/30/2016   2600   08/31/2016   2650
444128   10/31/2016   2700   09/30/2016   2600
```

Requesting your help and guidance

EDIT: What about something more like this, where EOM5 is calendar 06/30/2016 and EOM4 is calendar 07/31/2016, so the max date found in between those two dates with a record in the database would be 07/29/2016:

```
SELECT
MAX(DT_PRCE) AS "Max_Date_EOM4"
FROM UDBADM.D_PRICE_HIST
WHERE DT_PRCE BETWEEN
 (SELECT CURRENT DATE -(DAY(CURRENT_DATE)-1) DAYS - 4 MONTH - 1 DAY 
    AS "EOM5" FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
 AND (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE)-1) DAYS - 3 MONTH - 1 DAY
    AS "EOM4" FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with tmp1 as (
select id, price,
last_day(current date + (rownumber() over(order by id) - 7) month ) V_EOM,                                                    
last_day(current date + (rownumber() over(order by id) - 8) month) V_EOM_LAST                                                    
from UDBADM.D_PRICE_HIST WHERE ID = '444128' 
),
tmp2 as (
select id, price, V_EOM, 
case DAYOFWEEK(V_EOM_LAST) 
when 7 then V_EOM_LAST - 1 day
when 1 then V_EOM_LAST - 2 day
else V_EOM_LAST end as V_EOM_LAST
from tmp1
)

select f1.*, f2.price last_price from tmp2 f1 
LEFT JOIN UDBADM.D_PRICE_HIST f2 ON (f1.ID, f1.V_EOM_LAST)  = (f2.ID, f2.DT_PRCE)
```

Comment: Thank you, Esperento57. I should have mentioned that there are no records in the database for days that are holidays as well, so the weekend minus 1 or 2 days will not work if the max date in a month falls on a week day that is a holiday. Is there another way with a Max function?

Comment: I think I answered your question. But what you ask in addition is more difficult. The system does not have a function that manages the holidays (it is not feasible because the holidays depend on the country, the regions, etc). You should make yourself a table of holidays, with the beginning and the end of the holiday. So you could ask on it to subtract the number of days off if your last day is in the interval.

Comment: I can't get that to work. I really need the max date found in the database within the month of the rolling 6 months. Posted an updated example.

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand what you want. Put an example data before/data after please

for your second query dont use SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

if you want just select before 2 dates fixed

```
SELECT
MAX(DT_PRCE) AS "Max_Date_EOM4"
FROM UDBADM.D_PRICE_HIST
WHERE DT_PRCE BETWEEN cast('2016-06-30' as date) and cast('2016-07-37' as date)
```

if you want with last day

```
SELECT MAX(DT_PRCE) AS "Max_Date_EOM4"
FROM UDBADM.D_PRICE_HIST
WHERE DT_PRCE BETWEEN 
last_day(current date - 5 month) and
last_day(current date - 4 month)
```